# Size vs Size On Disk

Tags: filesystems, size, filesize, disk, diskspace

I read about the byte vs cluster theory, but I don't think it can apply in my case;
[image: wtf]

---

Doesn't seem to have to do with "a bunch of small files";
[image]

```
.
├── [ 11K]  2ndVisit_Checklist.xlsx
├── [ 35K]  2ndVisit FTS_Timetable.xlsx
├── [ 34K]  2ndVisit_Roomlist.pdf
├── [ 27K]  2ndVisit_Teilnehmer.xlsx
├── [9.5K]  Belgian Pupils for European Parliament.xlsx
├── [4.0K]  Brussel EU
│   ├── [ 64K]  Checkliste.doc
│   ├── [144K]  Plan A73.doc
│   ├── [ 38K]  TN Liste EP.docx
│   └── [108K]  TN Liste EP V02.doc
├── [ 12K]  Financial overview second visit.xlsx
├── [ 43K]  getting to know each other.doc
├── [ 62K]  Hotel_confirmation_dinner.pdf
├── [204K]  Letter_Parents_Agreement.docx
├── [239K]  Letter_Parents_Costs.docx
├── [ 17K]  Ouders regeling.docx
├── [ 12K]  Pictures
│   ├── [5.7M]  DSC_0007.JPG
│   ├── [7.3M]  DSC_0015.JPG
│   ├── [8.0M]  DSC_0017.JPG
│   ├── [8.5M]  DSC_0040.JPG
│   ├── [5.8M]  DSC_0041.JPG
│   ├── [5.2M]  DSC_0042.JPG
│   ├── [5.4M]  DSC_0046.JPG
│   ├── [6.2M]  DSC_0066.JPG
│   ├── [5.9M]  DSC_0074.JPG
│   ├── [8.2M]  DSC_0077.JPG
│   ├── [6.1M]  DSC_0080.JPG
│   ├── [8.7M]  DSC_0083.JPG
│   ├── [8.8M]  DSC_0086.JPG
│   ├── [8.5M]  DSC_0087.JPG
│   ├── [7.3M]  DSC_0094.JPG
│   ├── [4.6M]  DSC_0102.JPG
│   ├── [7.5M]  DSC_0120.JPG
│   ├── [7.8M]  DSC_0121.JPG
│   ├── [8.3M]  DSC_0123.JPG
│   ├── [7.6M]  DSC_0125.JPG
│   ├── [5.7M]  DSC_0130.JPG
│   ├── [8.5M]  DSC_0138.JPG
│   ├── [6.6M]  DSC_0164.JPG
│   ├── [7.2M]  DSC_0165.JPG
│   ├── [6.5M]  DSC_0169.JPG
│   ├── [6.9M]  DSC_0174.JPG
│   ├── [8.5M]  DSC_0196.JPG
│   ├── [7.0M]  DSC_0200.JPG
│   ├── [7.8M]  DSC_0214.JPG
│   ├── [8.5M]  DSC_0245.JPG
│   ├── [8.2M]  DSC_0258.JPG
│   ├── [8.2M]  DSC_0264.JPG
│   ├── [7.8M]  DSC_0270.JPG
│   ├── [7.9M]  DSC_0271.JPG
│   ├── [7.3M]  DSC_0273.JPG
│   ├── [5.9M]  DSC_0287.JPG
│   ├── [7.8M]  DSC_0293.JPG
│   ├── [7.9M]  DSC_0298.JPG
│   ├── [8.0M]  DSC_0299.JPG
│   ├── [7.5M]  DSC_0300.JPG
│   ├── [7.9M]  DSC_0304.JPG
│   ├── [6.1M]  DSC_0322.JPG
│   ├── [6.7M]  DSC_0330.JPG
│   ├── [7.1M]  DSC_0333.JPG
│   ├── [7.9M]  DSC_0338.JPG
│   ├── [7.2M]  DSC_0343.JPG
│   ├── [7.0M]  DSC_0348.JPG
│   ├── [6.5M]  DSC_0350.JPG
│   ├── [7.5M]  DSC_0359.JPG
│   ├── [7.2M]  DSC_0370.JPG
│   ├── [7.7M]  DSC_0399.JPG
│   ├── [8.4M]  DSC_0404.JPG
│   ├── [8.4M]  DSC_0409.JPG
│   ├── [8.5M]  DSC_0417.JPG
│   ├── [7.8M]  DSC_0424.JPG
│   ├── [8.0M]  DSC_0426.JPG
│   ├── [6.3M]  DSC_0429.JPG
│   ├── [7.6M]  DSC_0435.JPG
│   ├── [6.0M]  DSC_0443.JPG
│   ├── [6.7M]  DSC_0450.JPG
│   ├── [7.5M]  DSC_0453.JPG
│   ├── [6.9M]  DSC_0465.JPG
│   ├── [6.2M]  DSC_0475.JPG
│   ├── [7.6M]  DSC_0479.JPG
│   └── [6.2M]  DSC_0487.JPG
├── [ 80K]  Presentation First day.pptx
├── [ 12K]  price calculation activities 2nd visit.xlsx
├── [9.6K]  Prices in Turnhout.xlsx
├── [9.9K]  Regular lessons during visit for SO Zenit pupils.xlsx
└── [ 24K]  rules and stuff.doc

2 directories, 85 files
```

---

The directory in question is an NTFS filesystem, with a symlink from an EXT4 filesystem.

Comment: If you have a lot of small files, then each file will occupy the whole block, which results in internal fragmentation. Check whether this is the case here.

Comment: @nhahtdh Doesn't seem to be the case; see my edit.

Comment: Check out this case: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/%5Blubuntu%5D-files-size-on-disk-is-~-10x-total-size-of-files-930714/

Comment: @nhahtdh Oh well, as long as it doesn't actually take up that much space :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why byte vs cluster doesn't apply here.

The total size of the files represents the size of the actual files in bytes.  When files are stored on disk they often take up more space as they will use up complete clusters, even if the file is much smaller.

Based on the fact that this is an SVN directory, which typically has a large number of very small files, it would explain why the size on disk is much larger.  I file with only 10 bytes in it could take 2KB on disk depending on your cluster size.

Cluster sizes vary depending on the file system and the size of the hard drive.

Comment: As you can see in the directory tree above; Doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: Not really the answer to my particular question, but your answer could apply for other people. My particular experience seemed to be caused by a bug in PCManFM.